# GeoPandas spatial index - passing RTree parameters to index

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-index, rtree

I am quite familiar how to work with the Toblerity RTree library:

```
import fiona
import rtree

with fiona.open(input_path,'r') as source:   
    p = rtree.index.Property()
    p.filename = "index.idx"
    p.overwrite = False
    p.fill_factor=0.6 # some - absurd  - values for tunning the index
    p.get_pagesize=20 # another absurd value, for demo purposes   
    index = rtree.index.Index(properties=p) #create index
    for f in source:
        ... # process features, add to index etc
```

I am, however, wondering, how to pass `parameters` to an index when calling the Geopandas sindex on a GeoDataFrame:

```
gpd.sindex
```

does not take any arguments.

The documentation states that all parameters from RTree are [supported](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/sindex.html), but I am unsure how to pass them to the `sindex`.

Comment: The `sindex` attribute returns an already created spatial index object (either an `rtree` or `pygeos` tree object), so currently you cannot control how it is created (i.e. you can't pass custom parameters to its constructor)

Comment: Wonderful, thank you, good to know. Can you please add whether the index is now automatically created upon filling the GeoDataFrame, or is it called on-demand when calling sindex (that was my understanding).

Comment: Indeed, it is created on-demand on the first time accessing the `sindex` attribute.

Comment: @joris please post your comments as an answer so this thread can be marked as solved